# ASP.NET MVC - Master / Detail Posting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I am trying to create what I thought was a basic functionality. I have a view that is accessed via "http://myserver.com/Products/Ship/". When a user visits this page, they will be prompted for the serial number of a product. After a user enters the serial number and clicks "next", I want to show them a drop down list of shipping options. I want to do this while keeping them at the "http://www.myserver.com/Products/Ship" url. Because of this, I thought JQuery would be a suitable answer. In the process, I have run into a problem. I cannot get to the second page as desired.

For reference, my view code looks like this:

```
  <h2>Product Shipping</h2>
  <p><form id="myForm" action="/Products/Ship" method="post">
    <fieldset>               
      Product
      <%= Html.TextBox("product", null, new{@class = "required product"}) %> 

      <br />

      <input type="submit" value="OK" />        
    </fieldset>        
  </form></p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myForm").validate({ submitHandler: submitSerialNumber });
    });

    function submitSerialNumber () {
        $post("/Products/Ship", "", function(result) { alert("woohoo 1"); });
    }
</script>
```

My controller code looks like the following:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Ship()
{            
  return View();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult Ship(string serialNumber)
{
  // Ensure that a serial number was entered
  JsonResult result = null;
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(serialNumber))
  {
    result = Json(new { success = false, message = "Please enter a serial number" });
    return result;
  }


  // Obtain the list of options from the database. Hardcoded for testing            
  result = Json(new { success = true, message = "Option 1 | Option 2 | Option 3" });
  return result;
}
```

Right now, when I run the page, FireFox prompts me to save the Json result when I submit a serial number. Am I way off here? It seems like I should be able to just flip the view via JavaScript. However, the posting is making it tricky. I need a way to get some results from the database when a user enters a serial number.

Thank you

Comment: As Mark suggest, you need to set the callback function, to take care of that JSON result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code.  You should put quotes around the true and false values when returning the JSON object in your controller just to be safe.  Also, you can just handle the submit event yourself and not worry about doing it in the validate event of the form.  The return false tells the form to not actually submit it via a normal page refresh and by the ajax call instead.  You were also missing a period between $ and post in the ajax call.

All that being said, hopefully this fixes the problems.

View Code

```
 <h2>Product Shipping</h2>
  <p><form id="myForm" action="/Products/Ship" method="post">
    <fieldset>               
      Product
      <%= Html.TextBox("product", null, new{@class = "required product"}) %> 

      <br />

      <input type="submit" value="OK" />        
    </fieldset>        
  </form></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myForm").validate();
        $("#myForm input[type=submit]").submit(function() {
                    var serializedValues = $("#myForm").serialize();
            $.post("/Products/Ship", serializedValues, function(result) { 
                alert(result.success); 
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Ship()
{            
  return View();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult Ship(FormCollection fColl)
{
  // Ensure that a serial number was entered
  JsonResult result = null;
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fcoll["product"]))
  {
    result = Json(new { success = "false", message = "Please enter a serial number" });
    return result;
  }


  // Obtain the list of options from the database. Hardcoded for testing            
  result = Json(new { success = "true", message = "Option 1 | Option 2 | Option 3" });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your json result using

```
$.getJSON(url, callback);
```

Where callback is a function that will display your object. This will sort it, you need to have a select in the view and have your callback function add options to it from your json object.

In your case you will need to have a route defined in global asax or wherever you are creating routes, that accepts Product/Ship/SerialNumber and routes this to your Json result. This naming is a little confusing, you would be well advised to choose another name for the json result. Also the button should not submit the form, if you are using jQuery to add the values to an element that is already on the screen (maybe hidden).

Have a JSON result that outputs something like this

```
return Json(new{ OptionText = "Option 1", OptionValue = "1" });
```

You'll be able to see your output using something like this, jquery documentation 
will show you how to add the options into your select.

```
$.getJSON(url, null, function(json) { //null could be some input data
            alert(
            "This just shows the option value, "
            + json.OptionValue +
            "\nand the option text, "
            + json.OptionText
            );
        });
```

Comment: I don't understand. I have a callback defined. I also tried using getJSON instead of post. I am still getting a prompt to save the result returned from the controller.

Comment: If you look at other answers on this subject, it points to your JSON object being badly formed. The way to check this is to have firebug running, and see exactly what the json result returns. If you have a callback defined, stick an alert in so that you know it is being called.

Comment: Your form does not call submitSerialNumber(), you need to have a button (not a submit), so I would not expect to be hitting the callback, hope this helps.